# Detecting the location where a button was clicked

Tags: java, android, android-button

I was wondering if there is a way to know exactly where a button was tapped, and take different actions based on where the user tapped it. Something like:

```
fooBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(onClickLocation){
            case LEFT:
                foo();
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                bar();
                break;
            case MIDDLE:
                baz();
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The coordinates of the tap in relation to the button's coordinates and dimensions seems like a logical start.

Answer (score 1):

Not using an `OnClickListener`. `OnTouchListener` gives you a `MotionEvent` that you can use to determine where the actual touch event occurred.

For example, here I register *both* an `OnClickListener` and an `OnTouchListener` on the same `View` (called `row`):

```
row.setOnClickListener(this);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  row.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      v
        .findViewById(R.id.row_content)
        .getBackground()
        .setHotspot(event.getX(), event.getY());

      return(false);
    }
  });
}
```

In this case, I don't need to know where the widget was touched for processing the click, but I do need to know where the widget was touched for adjusting the `RippleDrawable` background, so the ripple appears to emanate from where the user touched. Returning `false` from `onTouch()` means I am not consuming the touch event, and so eventually my `onClick()` method will also be called.

In your case, either:

- do the actual work in `onTouch()`, or
- cache the last-seen touch point in `onTouch()` but do not do the work until `onClick()`

My gut tells me that the latter should give you better results (e.g., you won't misinterpret a long-click), but I have not tried doing what you are seeking.

Comment: This will not work as it will only deliver the getId from the outer most widget (row). How can I detect which one of my two child widgets that was clicked (i.e get the clicked getId of the clicked child widget from row)?

Comment: @powder366: "This will not work as it will only deliver the getId from the outer most widget (row)" -- um, this code is not using `getId()`. "How can I detect which one of my two child widgets that was clicked" -- call `setOnTouchListener()` on each widget. Or, IIRC, there are methods on `ViewGroup` that can give you the child at a given x/y coordinate within the `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Using setOnTouchListener works but then the event to onTouch and it's setHotspot never get called, seems now my child view onTouch consumes the event and do not deliver it to the outer most view row. Any idea?

Comment: I could not figure it out. As soon I returned true once in my onTouch, onTouch setHotspot never got called. I solved it by always returning false and then working with setting a variable that I then check in my onClick.